# Anylogic Image index change in simulation window

Tags: anylogic

I have 5 pictures in the image properties in simulation window. I would like the images to be changing every  5 seconds. In Image properties advanced section i can change the picture manually using image index. Can I use while loop to do such operation in simulation window?
If yes How can I implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simulation window you can do this on the initial experiment setup java action:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        
        while(true){
            image.setIndex(image.getIndex()==image.getImageCount()-1 ? 0 : image.getIndex()+1);

            try{
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }catch(Exception e){
            
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

This will require to add in the advanced section, on the imports section: `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`

Comment: I am using the image into the simulation window not the main. I cant use event in simulation.

Comment: Thanks Felipe and thanks for the noorjax.teachable.com.